# Remove everything between specific brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a particular paragraph like this :

> Hi. This is so [abc="12"]awesome[/abc] that everytime I post a
>   [abc="456"]question[/abc] at stack, it gets [answered] within the next 5
>   [abc="53"]minutes[/abc].

I want to remove all the `abc` tags between (and including) `[]` using regex. I don't want to remove JUST anything between `[]` because that would also remove `[answered]` which isnt an `abc` tag.

Basically, remove everything between `[` and `]` when it also contains the text `abc`.

I have been able to get to

```
<%=movieProduct.getSynopsis().replaceAll("[.*] *", "") %>
```

but it doesnt work, plus I dont know how to search for abc.

Comment: \\[/?abc.*?\]|\\[|\\]

will match all brackets and abc tags with the result of Hi. This is so awesome that everytime I post a question at stack, it gets answered within the next 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work to select all required tags :

```
\[/?abc.*?\]
```

## demo :

http://regexr.com?33u9u

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
replaceAll("\\[abc.*?\\].*?\\[\\/abc\\]", "")
```

to erase everything between the tags. Don't forget to escape special characters using `\` when working with regexes.

If you want to keep the text inside the tags, you can use

```
replaceAll("\\[abc.*?\\](.*?)\\[\\/abc\\]", "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex:

```
"[[].*abc.*?[]]"
```

or alternatively

```
movieProduct.getSynopsis().replaceAll("[[]abc.+?[]](.+?)[[]/abc[]]", "$1");
```