# SQLite: How to remove brackets and all text in between?

Tags: sql, sqlite, replace, sql-update

I have a row of data that needs some "scrubbing" before it's usable. Since the data enters

from an external source I can't control what enters the table. Instead I need to do some

extensive "scrubbing" a few times a week.

Example data:

> Upptäck tron: [har livet mening?] : [vad påstår Jesus?] : [är tron till för alla?]

I want to remove the brackets and all text in between them. (The colons are removed later.)

I was trying this command

> UPDATE Table SET Table=REPLACE(Field,[.?],'');

and

> UPDATE Table SET Table=REPLACE(Field,'[.?]','');

but it doesn't seem to work.
Since I'm new to SQLite I feel a bit lost. The problem is similar to

[Remove everything between specific brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110716) but I need a pure SQL-query for SQLite.

Has anybody got an idea of how to tackle this problem? (An example would be much

appreciated.)

Comment: I do not think that it is doable in pure SQL.  While SQLite supports regular expressions, it does not have associated replace functionality.  You can `filter` by regexp but can't `replace` with it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in SQL do it at the application layer.